# Query to identify duplicates based on time of day

Tags: sql, ms-access

SQL newbie here. I have a table with trainer schedules. Each record within the table, **Schedule**, contains the following relevant fields: 
**course_code**, 
**training_date**, 
**start_time**, 
**end_time**, 
**trainer**, 
**room**

I would like a query to identify whenever a trainer or a room is double-booked. The query wizard gets me pretty far, but obviously my need is a bit more complex than the wizard's capability. I was able to generate this query:

```
SELECT Schedule.[training_date], Schedule.[trainer], Schedule.[course_code]
FROM Schedule
WHERE (((Schedule.[training_date]) In (SELECT [training_date] FROM [Schedule] As Tmp GROUP BY [training_date],[trainer] HAVING Count(*)>1  And [trainer] = [Schedule].[trainer])) AND (Not (Schedule.[course_code])="OP00487"))
ORDER BY Schedule.[training_date], Schedule.[trainer];
```

It returns the course codes where trainers are booked multiple times in any given day, but I would like to exclude those records where the trainer is training two different times. For example, *OP1* might be taught *9:00* to *12:30*, and *OP2* is taught *12:30* to *16:00*. In this case, this is not a duplicate within the date that I care about. I do want to see the record if a trainer is teaching *8:00* to *12:00* and also *10:30* to *14:00*.

My query does exclude one **course_code** because duplicates for that code are irrelevant. I will also have the same thing with the room query (doesn't matter how many *off site* **rooms** overlap).

I should be able to engineer the **room** query based on the **trainer** query, but if both could be integrated into one query, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery.  The following should find any overlap in time on the same date for a training or room:

```
select s.*
from schedule as s
where exists (select 1
              from schedule as s2
              where (s2.trainer = s.trainer or s2.room = s.room) and
                    s2.training_date = s.training_date and
                    s2.start_time < s.end_time and
                    s2.end_time > s.start_time and
                    s2.schedule_id <> s.schedule_id
              );
```

Note that this postulates the existence of a column called `schedule_id` to prevent the query from finding that any given record overlaps with itself.

Comment: Thank you. You're right that I do have schedule_id to keep things unique.

Comment: Oops, sorry, posted too early.

I tried adding a duplicate entry on my table, but it doesn't show up in the query. Am I correct in interpreting that the "as s" and "as s2" are defined only in the query for ease of use? I don't need to replace those with anything else from my table, right?

Comment: @KevinElmore . . . Those are aliases for the references to the `schedule` table.  It is important that they be different in the inner and outer queries.  What they are specifically doesn't matter, as long as they are used consistently.

Comment: I figured out why my query kept coming up empty. My time data were stored as text ("9:00:00 AM"). I have converted them to just numbers. I wouldn't mind finding a way to deal with a simpler version of that text ("13:00" for example), but I'm good with these numbers.

I do have an issue with training slots that are supposed to have multiple trainers since that triggers the criterion. I may have to consider an exception column that marks this double-booking as acceptable. I'll ponder on that and come back if I have any further questions. Thanks!